# Различие между словарем и списком

Tags: python, list, dict

Прошу прощения если этот вопрос уже задавали но подскажите пожалуйста почему в 
      этом коде на выходе будет [2,2,2], грубо говоря три двойки

```
A=[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2]
res = list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,A))
print (res)
```

А в этом [2], то есть одна двойка

```
A={1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2}
res = list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,A))
print (res)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может я конечно и ошибаюсь, но {} без ключей это множество, а в этом типе данных каждый элемент встречается только ОДИН раз , поэтому итератор и останавливается на первой встречной двойке.

Comment: Не останавливается на первой двойке, а там в А всего одна двойка.